# How to color like numbers in a table with the same color?

Tags: javascript

I have the following scenario:

1. The numbers will keep changing randomly and in real time;
2. It may be that these numbers come with random or equal values ​​compared with the next one;

What problem am I facing?

I did a test with the algorithm below, but if you noticed, in line 2 it inserts "even" which is correct, because the current value is different from the next one, however, the new values ​​are equal to the current one and it inserts "odd ", but it should come with "even", and from line 11 it's the same case, but since it should be "even" before line 11, line 11 and 12 should be "odd".

[image]

```js
const tst = [
 { buy: 84.16 },
 { buy: 84.16 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
 { buy: 84.15 },
];

let className = [];

tst.forEach((el, i) => {
 const OLD_ELEMENT = tst[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1].buy;
 className.push(el.buy === OLD_ELEMENT ? 'odd' : 'even');

 console.log(`${el.buy}:${OLD_ELEMENT} --- ${className[i]}`);
})
```

Comment: What does 'even' and 'odd' mean here? Can you please be specific? It's clear it's not being used to mean the classical definition of even and odd...

Comment: I can not understand what your actual problem is. The numbers are matching so it is setting odd.... you are saying it should not be doing that? What are the exact rules.

Comment: Please share the expected output.

Comment: I think I've realized what he's trying to do: he's trying to change the className from even to odd, or vice-versa, every time the value changes in the array. So if my array is `[a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d]`, it would come out as `[o,o,e,e,e,o,o,o,o,e]` -- all consecutive same values are the same class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a helper function that will *turn around* the `prev` value.

THen use use the `prev` if it's the same value, otherwise, you call the helper function

```js
const tst = [{ buy: 84.16 }, { buy: 84.16 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 } ];
const reversePrev = () => (prev = prev === 'odd' ? 'even' : 'odd');

let prev = 'odd';

tst.forEach((el, i) => {
    const OLD_ELEMENT = tst[i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1].buy;
    const oe = (OLD_ELEMENT === el.buy) ? prev : reversePrev();
    console.log(`${el.buy}:${OLD_ELEMENT} --- ${oe}`);
});
```

```
84.16:84.16 --- odd
84.16:84.16 --- odd
84.15:84.16 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
84.15:84.15 --- even
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of changes and then choose the colour based on whether the change count is odd or even; something like:

```js
const tst = [ { buy: 84.16 }, { buy: 84.16 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, { buy: 84.15 }, ];

const with_row_colour = (items, colours = ['light', 'dark']) => {
  let with_colour = [];
  let change_count = 0;
  
  for(const [index, item] of items.entries()) {
    if(items[index - 1]?.buy !== item.buy)
      change_count++;
    
    with_colour.push({ ...item, colour: colours[change_count % 2] });
  }
  
  return with_colour;
};

console.log(with_row_colour(tst));
```